# Phalcon form sanitize

Tags: php, phalcon, sanitization

[image]Is there a way in which one can filter data that is auto-completed in a form generated by VOLT.
Consider the login form: Email/password.
When I edit the HTML (in the broser) and send the email as an array ('**name="email[]**") **I can sanitize it in PHP and 'cast' as en email**:

```
            $loginEmail = $this->request->getPost("email",'string');
            $loginEmail = $this->filter->sanitize($loginEmail, "email");
```

in order to prevent other attacks.
But when making the email field an array VOLT generates an error:

```
"Notice: Array to string conversion in ..."
```

VOLT form values are populated automatically...

I know I should disable NOTICES in production but still...

How can I treat this by using VOLT?

***EDIT***
Template sample:

```
{{ text_field('id':"email","class":"form-control", "size": 32,"placeholder":'Email address') }}
```

After a var_dump and setting the email string through validation I get at a certain point:

```
protected '_viewParams' => 
    array (size=5)
      'title' => string 'Test' (length=5)
      'showSlider' => boolean true
      'hideUnlogged' => boolean true
      'user' => null
      'email' => boolean false
```

BUT the variables are sent to VOLT in an upper layer because it is still set as an ARRAY.

The only viable solution is to make an object or something and get from a config what validation rules to apply to forms (by name) and rewrite the post variable in **public/index.php** something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
    $_POST['email'] = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}
```

If anyone has a better solution in which this can be done in a controller rather that this or in a service with event handlers...

Comment: I'm lost a little. The error occurs in the Volt template when you pass it the form data that contains array instead of the string, correct? You need to validate that form data and sanitise it before passing to the template, correct?

Comment: Another thing that I'm unclear about is when you send `email` as an array the name of the input changes from `email` to `email[]`. So, if `email` is specified as the form element name, the form should be getting that value, not `email[]`. In other words unless there is an bug somewhere, there should be no way of getting an array instead of the string unless you are expecting it…

Comment: I ran a vulnerability scan, and this came up and am a bit frustrated by this because it should be easy to bypass this. This shouldn`t happen but there is the saying: NEVER TRUST USER SUBMITTED DATA (Cross-site scripting, injections etc).

Comment: I agree on that, I just don't get the picture of what's happening on the server. Does it happen in the template when you are rendering it? Does the template take values from the form? If so, can you include form code? If not, can you describe what's going on in the action which handles the request (before you get to the template rendering)?

Comment: It happens when I submit the form with wrong credentials (before  submitting I altered the name of the email and pass as an Array), volt tries to prefill the submitted data ($_POST vars into the form) then the notice occurs. He tries to echo $_POST['email']...

Comment: Yes, but before Volt fills the submitted data many things happen: your router finds out and tells dispatcher what controller / action to run, then inside your controller / action POST data (can be and should be) processed, usually a Form component can be used for that, and then if it's valid some logic is performed and THEN the values are passed to the view, which is ONLY THEN gets rendered using Volt engine.

Comment: I have the LoginController and index.volt, a fix I found is to register a VOLT filter : return  '@Validation::string_cast(' . $resolvedArgs . ')';//suppress when $_POST is empty, and changing in index.volt : {{ text_field('value':email|string_cast,'id'...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60203/discussion-between-ian-bytchek-and-ka-lin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do anything you wish by [implementing a custom filter](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/filter.html#creating-your-own-filters) and doing a proper conversion from array to string.

```
$filter = new \Phalcon\Filter();

//Using an anonymous function
$filter->add('superSanitisedString', function($value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        $value = empty($value) ? '' : reset($value);
    }
    return (string) $value;
});

//Sanitize with the "superSanitisedString" filter
$filtered = $filter->sanitize($possibleArray, "superSanitisedString");
```

But… don't bend the stick too much – this is a clear validation job and then sanitisation. Check that the value is a string, if not – ask to provide one. It's easier and smarter to protect your app from invalid inputs than from idiots who provide that input :)

**Edit:**

You can use a custom volt filter which can be added as a service, implement a class with a static method to return the sanitized value and use it in the template.

Comment: I found out than if I detect that if the request is $_POST I can overwrite the value (I can use your example of custom filter) sent to the template by using $this->view->email = (string)$sanitizedString (as example)

Comment: I was intrigued that the framework doesn`t do it or they didn`t prevent this

Comment: Yep. To make things more fluent you can extend the `Request` class with your own logic and to add `setPost($name, $value)` – Phalcon doesn't give it out of the box. And if you have some general rules for request values you can also add them directly into the `Request` component.

Comment: Unfortunately I have the same issue even if I set $this->view->email = $sanitizedString, I think the prepopulation is done on an upper layer